# How to insert ObjectId to PostgreSQL

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am writing a script in which I fetch data from MongoDB and dump it into PostgreSQL. Everything works fine but when I try to insert the MongoDBs ObjectId `_id`, it gives the following error.

> (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) trailing junk after numeric literal at
> or near "63711d"

I want to insert the `_id` in the PostgreSQL db as primary key, so that duplicate rows do not exist.

The query generated by psycopg2 is as follows

```
[SQL: INSERT INTO employees (_id, candidate_last_name, candidate_first_name, candidate_state, candidate_experience, candidate_relocation, candidate_skills, candidate_specialty)VALUES (6375364d1ad809ab6108a544, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), (6375364d1ad809ab6108a545, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)]
```

The `_id` field in PostgreSQL is VARCHAR.

The code that I am using is as follows:

```
def insert_psql(db, table_name: str, fields: dict, data: list):

    new_fields = {}
    for field in fields:
        new_fields[field.replace('.', '_')] = fields[field]
    insert_query = f'INSERT INTO {table_name} ('
    insert_query += ', '.join(new_fields.keys()) + ')'
    insert_query += 'VALUES '
    for i, row in enumerate(data):
        insert_query += '('
        for j, field in enumerate(fields):
            if not row.get(field):
                insert_query += 'NULL'
            else:
                insert_query += f'{str(row.get(field))}'
            if not j == len(fields) - 1:
                insert_query += ', '
        insert_query += ')'
        if not i == len(data) - 1:
            insert_query += ', '
    # print(insert_query)
    try:
        db.execute(insert_query)
        db.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The fields dict is a dictionary containing column names and their data_types as value. The data list a list of records to insert

Comment: How do you generate the insert statement? If this is a VARCHAR in PostgreSQL, then the value should be enclosed in quotes in the generated statement.

Comment: Could you add the code that generates this query to your post?

Comment: I am generating insert query dynamically. I have added the code for this in the post.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel any Idea how to resolve this error ?

Comment: You should not create statements through concatenation. Use prepared statements with parameters. Your current code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error code is: `trailing junk after numeric literal at or near "63711d"`

Specifically, it is warning about unexpected characters after *numeric* literals. In the text that is printed we can see five digits (`63711`) followed by the character `a`. It seems that the code is attempting to parse this set of characters as a number and failing to do so once it finds the first alpha character.

Indeed when we look at the SQL statement that is generated we can see this:

```
VALUES (6375364d1ad809ab6108a544,
```

If you are attempting to insert a string (`VARCHAR`), then [@Mark Rotteveel said what you need to do in the very first comment on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74518627/how-to-insert-objectid-to-postgresql?noredirect=1#comment131543163_74518627):

> If this is a VARCHAR in PostgreSQL, then the value should be enclosed in quotes in the generated statement.

Your `INSERT` statement should presumably have something like this instead:

```
VALUES ('6375364d1ad809ab6108a544',
```

*Edited to use single quotes instead of double. Also, Mark raises another important warning about this approach overall [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74518627/how-to-insert-objectid-to-postgresql/74519975?noredirect=1#comment131563146_74518627).*

Comment: It should look like `VALUES ('6375364d1ad809ab6108a544',` (single quotes, not double quotes).

Comment: Oops, fixed! Also pointed to your warning about the approach overall in the comments